# datetime2 conversion to specific datetime format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

whats the best way of converting `detetime2` to a `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` format in SQL Server 2008?

I a column with `datetime2` stamps. I am looking to convert it at `SELECT`-ion time.

I had a look at [MSDN for reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx) where `CONVER(VARCHAR(16), detetime2, 131)` seems to be the closes to my requirement. Only two issue with it. The date part doesn't get zero padded and it converting time to 12 hour clock.

Anyone with a constructive suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x datetime2 = Current_Timestamp;

SELECT @x
     , Convert(char(10), @x, 103) + ' ' + Convert(char(5), @x, 108)
;
```

Comment: P.S. if you were using SQL Server 2012 or later, you could use the `Format()` function for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: I wish I was buddy. But I am doing this for someone else. Thank you for a quick answer. Worked like a charm for me.